# Browser Back Button Issues

Tags: jquery, browser, iframe, button, back

I have one issue if you have solution, please advise asap

1. I have the  HTML page and PHP file.
2. I  have one image, While clicking that image, an Iframe will be opened. Then the transactions will be continuing within that Iframe.
3. When Iframe opens, the browser back button should not work. If Iframes closes, then the browser back button should work.
4. I am using jquery.colorbox.js for Iframe pop up
5. Keyboard back arrow and Back using right click mouse also should not work.
6. Need explanation with example

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible:

[this has been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243684/disable-back-button-in-browser-using-jquery) - [asked several times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359941/how-to-disable-back-button-navigation-on-certain-pages) - [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961188/disable-browsers-back-button).

I would use jQuery's [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) instead of frames.