# Logout still access to authorize page when click on browser back button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Login and Logout method with remember me. After Logout from 'index' page(authorized), I can still go back to 'index' with browser's(chrome) back arrow. Is this because of remember me? How can I totally logout from my website?

This happens even Remember Me is checked or not checked. I tried clearing browser cache and history.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals(loginModel.Username) && u.Password.Equals(loginModel.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserPkID.ToString(), loginModel.RememberMe);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
```

Comment: After you logout, and then go back, are you still able to interact with the website as if you were still logged in? (For example, logout > back > do_some_action_requiring_authentication) I ask this as I suspect your browser may be showing a cached copy of the site when you go back.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315742/after-logout-if-browser-back-button-press-then-it-go-back-last-screen

Comment: @Kei when i go back after logging out, I can't do any action and I reached to login page when I do some action.

Comment: Ah okay, in that case, it looks like your logout is fine and the issue is with the way the browser handles history. You could try Muhammad Aftab's answer below (but note that it will prevent users from using the back button) or one of the solutions in the link suggested by Hari Hara Chandan above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this block inside your `Global.asax` after `Application_Start()` function inside `public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication{}`

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
 {
 // Application_Start() and other functions

   protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. But when I click back button for like 2 or 3 times. Username appear in login form. Is it normal? Is is okay to show someone's username to other? Sorry, I'm asking this because I'm very new to development field and this is my first project.

Comment: @THA because you are already saved username and password in browser. that you have to clear by browser cashe clearing

Comment: And while downvoting please specify the reason behind it.. without any clarification somebody is doing it !Either you have to give any better solution for it.

Comment: @THA Not you!  Somebody else. happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

No this is not because of remember me.

you must push your url in pushState and clean the browser history:

try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        window.history.pushState(null, "", window.location.href);        
        window.onpopstate = function() {
            window.history.pushState(null, "", window.location.href);
        };
    });
```

check here:
[Disable Back Button in Browser using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243684/disable-back-button-in-browser-using-jquery)